# Jenny's not picking up 100 dollar note

Tags: lateral-thinking

One day Jenny was going to a market through a road. She saw a 100 dollar note in the road. Though she was able to pick up the note, she didn't pick up it. Why?

(The note wasn't torn, artificial or inactive)

Comment: _"she didn't pick up it"_. Is this a hidden clue or a typo?

Comment: I downvoted: on top of all the answers listed, there are still others that fit and are all justifiable reasons to not pick up the note (e.g. Jenny may be a millionaire, someone may have already been over there picking it up, she may have seen the person who dropped it who was returning to collect it).

Comment: I do sort of wish there was scope for lateral thinking questions like this on this site.  I really enjoyed guessing at these at school.  But I guess I can see why even some classic lateral thinking problems with well established solutions may cause problems here in terms of quality control and such...  Still a shame.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps

> The note was 'in the road'. So the road was very busy so she didn't pick it up as she'd rather live than attempt to pick it up

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the writing of the question was intentional...

> Jenny was driving a pickup truck through that road.

One day Jenny was going to a market through a road.

> She was going *through* the road, not *across* it.

She saw a 100 dollar note in the road.

> The note was *in* the road, not over it, therefore she couldn't get a hold of the note.

Though she was able to pick up the note, she didn't pick up it.

> She didn't *pick up it* could be interpreted as "she didn't run over it with her pickup truck". Otherwise, a better phrasing would have been "She didn't pick it up". It seems fairly intentional that in all instances of the expression, "pick" is immediately followed by "up".

So I believe she didn't pick up the note because...

> It could damage the note by going over it. Or perhaps it was on another lane, or somewhere she wouldn't drive by. Or maybe she just didn't feel like driving over a 100 dollar note for no apparent reason.

Comment: _"The note was in the note"_. Brilliant!

Comment: Hahahah, well spotted. Thanks for pointing out! I've fixed it :P

Answer (score 2):

she might have suspected that

> it could be *social experiment*, which is viral nowadays.

Answer (score 1):

Haha! This reminded me of a joke (not a PG one) so...

> She is wearing a short skirt, but no underwear. So she can't pick it up because that will be like... <s>stripteasing</s> not an appropriate thing to do in public.

Answer (score 1):

I VTC'd as too broad, based on the fact that I can think of a lot of answers that fit, in addition to the ones that others have answered.

> Jenny was a pig in the back of a truck, going to market to be butchered.

or

> Jenny was playing Monopoly, passed the Free Parking Space, and was not able to grab the money from that house rule.

or

> The note had something indescribably disgusting on it.

Comment: The note wasn't artificial. I guess that rules out Monopoly money.

Comment: +1 for the first answer, as that was my thinking as well (i.e. the money is worthless to Jenny)

Answer (score 0):

If Jenny is anything like me she didn't pick it up because

> she doesn't want to risk being branded a thief

Or

> Jenny lives in a Fallout-esque post-apocalyptic world where paper money is mostly worthless.

Or

> The note is not a note in the sense of "bill", but in the sense of "promissory note". That is, the note indicates that you *owe* someone 100 dollars.